# Why does filtering with an empty array crash with versions newer than 2.0.1?

Tags: ios, realm

I am trying to filter Results with the following predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (id IN %@)", arrayOfIDs)
```

When the array is empty and I try `results.filter(predicate)` my application is crashing with the message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'IN clause requires an array of items'

but this only happens in versions 2.0.4+, while in 2.0.1 it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or were there changes in the filtering implementation?

Comment: The implementation was changed long ago to require a non-nil value. You can see the relevant line of code [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMQueryUtil.mm#L860). Are you sure your array is empty, as opposed to nil? An empty array will pass the check in that  code; a nil value will not.

Comment: @AustinZ Yes, I'm sure it's not nil, I have tried printing it and its size and it's an empty array.

Comment: RealmJava seems to have an open issue about this matter [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4011) but I couldn't find anything about the Cocoa version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for digging up that link! This sounds like a bug; would you be willing to file a ticket at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues so we can investigate further?

Comment: Posted the issue [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5317). Thanks for the help :)